# BlockingCollection multiple consumers per group FIFO

Tags: c#, queue, fifo

I have a single producer that insert messages into a BlockingCollection.

The messages in the collection each have a groupId. The count of different groupIds is dynamic. The messages per group must be processed in FIFO order.
The work that the consumers do is a small calculation and a database insert, sometimes an additional http request.

I tried to create a new consumer thread for each groupId - but there are problems with too many threads.

The messages are processed a lot faster when I create 50 consumer threads like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        foreach (var item in _queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            var group = item.groupId;
            // do work
        }
    }
}
```

But with this code the messages per groupId are not processed in serial order.

Is there an easy way to make the consumer "sticky" per groupId?

e.g.: when a message with groupId 7 was processed by consumer 3 all further messages with groupId 7 must be processed by consumer 3.

Comment: Perhaps a `ConcurrentDictionary<int, Lazy<Tuple<BlockingCollection, WhatEverYourConsumerTypeIs>>>`? This would allow you to have a fixed consumer per groupid (key of the `ConcurrentDictionary`). Then use `TakeFromAny` so that each consumer reads messages from all of its `BlockingCollection`s.

Comment: Why not use one BlockingCollection per groupid?

Comment: I already tried with `ConcurrentDictionary<int, Tuple<BlockingCollection<dynamic>, SingleGroupProcessor>>` and create a consumer Task for each Dictionary Entry. The problem is when there are over 2000 different groupIds I have as many threads - or am I thinking wrong here?

Comment: I think you should look into TPL DataFlow, this is a bit messy

Comment: There is no need to create a new processor per groupid. You can have a single processor processing multiple groupids.

Comment: @mjwills do you have an example for that?